# How do you select a whole column in visual block mode?

Tags: vim

Say that I have this simple text in (g)Vim:

```
a  b  c
a  b  c
a  b  c
a  b  c
a  b  c
```

after changing to visual block selection mode how can I can select the whole 3rd column? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> selects whole text. I am looking for a keyboard shortcut for selecting a whole column selection, if any exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

<kbd>G</kbd> goes to the last line, but moves the cursor to the first non-blank position if the [`startofline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27startofline%27) or [`compatible`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27compatible%27) (which enables `startofline`) options are set. If you want to keep the same column, set `nosol` before going into visual block mode, and then hit <kbd>G</kbd>.

From the manual entry for `startofline`:

> When "on" the commands listed below move the cursor to the first non-blank of the line.  When off the cursor is kept in the same column (if possible).  This applies to the commands: CTRL-D, CTRL-U, CTRL-B, CTRL-F, "G", "H", "M", "L", gg, and to the commands "d", "<<" and ">>" with a linewise operator, with "%" with a count and to buffer changing commands (CTRL-^, :bnext, :bNext, etc.).

Comment: Nice, "set nosol" goes right into my .vimrc. I actually liked the deleted answer as well, for an unknown length file 9999j or a big number does the trick for the same column selection.

Comment: If your .vimrc also sets `compatible`, make sure `set nosol` comes after that line.

Comment: This has been bugging me for ages, thank you! Straight in the .vimrc as Gökhan Sever says :)

Comment: Anything that would work with `}` if the table does not occupy the entire file (e.g. aligned markdown table)?

Comment: I like this video, which shows in action the column selection, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuLy5LzHEzU

Answer (score 93):

<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> enters block selection mode (allowing you to select rectangular blocks of text). In gvim this conflicts with Windows' paste shortcut, so you can use <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd> instead.

Unfortunately, <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd> [G] doesn't do what you'd like since the [G] motion moves linearly through the file, so you still need to rely on a using a counted [j] motion. You can avoid having to know exactly how big the file is by using an obscenely large count, like 9999. So the full command is <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd> [9999j].

Alas I don't know of way that will avoid the ugly count hack offhand.

EDIT: Oh, I read your question too fast and missed that you already mentioned that you new about the visual block mode. I guess this is a pretty useless answer, then, sorry!

Comment: I came here because I forgot how to do vertical visual selection. This helped!

Answer (score 9):

The easy way for selecting column you can use plugin [vis.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195)

go to visual mode, select column `ctrl+v` , then you can do whatever you want with it

Use <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to visually mark some region.Then type `:B cmd` (this command will appear as:   `:'<,'>B cmd`)

The command will then be applied to just the visually selected region.

For example:

Use `ctrl-v` to select a column and then do a substitute on just that column.

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> ..move.. `:B s/pattern/becomes/`

Use <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> to select a column, then apply an external filter to just that column:

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> ..move.. `:B !sort`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure I'm not the only one who came here looking for a solution to a more general problem. Say I have:

```
Some text.

one two three
one two three
one two three
one two three
one two three
one two three

Some more text.
```

The following macro will select eg. all of the 'two' column when the cursor is anywhere inside it:

```
<C-v>iWmw{joO`woOmwoO}koO`w
```

### How it works

- `<C-v>iW` visual block select in Word (can of course have different macros for `iw`, `a"` etc.)
- `mw` Set mark at the right boundary
- `{j` Go to the start of the paragraph

Assuming you started somewhere in the middle, at this point your selection will look like this, where uppercase represents selected characters and `$` represents the cursor:

```
Some text.

$NE Two three
ONE Two three
ONE Two three
one two three
one two three
one two three

Some more text.
```

`oO` swaps the cursor to the corner on the same side (left) but the other end (bottom):

```
Some text.

ONE Two three
ONE Two three
$NE Two three
one two three
one two three
one two three

Some more text.
```

`` `w `` will now get you back to the right boundary:

```
Some text.

one TWO three
one TWO three
one TW$ three
one two three
one two three
one two three

Some more text.
```

`` oOmwoO}koO`w `` repeats the process for going down to the bottom of the paragraph.

Result:

```
Some text.

one TWO three
one TWO three
one TWO three
one TWO three
one TWO three
one $WO three

Some more text.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the beginning of the first line you can do:

```
ww ............... jump to the third column
Ctrl-v } ......... jump to the end of paragraph
```

If you have a blank line after just type then:

```
gE ............... goes back to the end of third column
```

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+v is visual block.
So just press ctrl+shift+v and then use cursor keys to select what you want.
[image]

There is also ctrl+shift+I for block insert